# Display categories belonging to Expresso Store entries

Tags: expresso-store, categories

It's easy to display categories in ExpressionEngine where entries are assigned using:

`{exp:channel:categories channel="products|book_library" category_group="13" style="linear" parent_only="yes" show_empty="no"}
<li><a href="{path='shop'}">{category_name}</a></li>
{/exp:channel:categories}`

However we're using Expresso Store and wish to display only the categories for which a store entry exists (i.e. entries with prices set in the Store publish tab).

The reasoning being that we use two channels for products, a specific shop products channel (products) and then another (book_library) where some entries will be available to buy, others will not.

Is there some way to do this without having to resort to some serious hackery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, probably hard to do in a categories loop. I would try using a product search loop (`{exp:store:search}`) along with the `search:price:min="0.01"` parameter (see the [search paramater](https://exp-resso.com/docs/search_tag.html) docs). You might have to do this once and silently assemble a PHP array of entry IDs and category IDs, sort them by category, then output in groups.